# Can someone explain how to capitalize all the elements in a Python List?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

```
cars = ['bmw', 'audi', 'toyota', 'subaru']
cars=[car.capitalize()for car in cars]
print(cars)
```

cars=[car.capitalize()for car in cars] This code can capitalize all the elements in the Cars list
But I don't know the logic behind this code.

I try to use these following codes to the same job as the above code, but they can't capitalize on all the elements in the Cars list. Did I miss some important steps?

```
cars = ['bmw', 'audi', 'toyota', 'subaru']
A=[]
for car in cars:
    car.capitalize()
    A.append(car)
print(A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so `car.capitalize()` doesn't change variable `car`, but returns new string that is capitalized:

```
cars = ['bmw', 'audi', 'toyota', 'subaru']
A=[]
for car in cars:
    A.append(car.capitalize())
print(A)
```

Prints:

```
['Bmw', 'Audi', 'Toyota', 'Subaru']
```

Comment: A.append(car) can return a new string? I thought the computer just put all the elements into the list A. I understand the second line of the for loop is an old string. But, I don't understand why the A.append(car)  is a new string?

Comment: @PhilipXiao No, `A.append(car.capitalize())` will append new string created by `car.capitalize()` to list `A`